# MQ client application connect to a client

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I wrote a client application to connect to MQ. It is working fine on svrconn channel, but not working on other channels.

My code:

```
try {
    // Create a connection factory
    JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
    JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

    // Set the properties
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
    cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
    cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QMGR);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
    cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, APP_USER);
    cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, APP_PASSWORD);

    // Create JMS objects
    context = cf.createContext();
    destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME);

    long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
    TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber);

    producer = context.createProducer();
    producer.send(destination, message);
    System.out.println("Sent message:\n" + message);

    consumer = context.createConsumer(destination); // autoclosable
    String receivedMessage = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 15000); // in ms or 15 seconds

    System.out.println("\nReceived message:\n" + receivedMessage);

    recordSuccess();
}
```

Please help with these 2 questions:

1. How can I connect to a qmgr which is in client mode?
2. How can I make this code connect to other channels as well?

Right now, when I try to use other channel it gives below error:

`JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to a queue manager 'qmgr name' with connection mode 'Client'`

Comment: Can you clarify what other channels you want to connect to?  A MQ client can only connect to a SVRCONN channel.   If you try to connect a MQ client to a RCVR or other channel type it will fail.  If this is what you are asking I'll write up a answer with some more details.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "a qmgr which is in client mode?" You say that you have successfully connected your application to a SVRCONN channel. This means you are successfully connecting your application to the queue manager in client mode. To be clear, it is the "application connection" that is in client mode, not the queue manager.

Comment: Yes, @JoshMc. That is what I meant. Why can this code connect only to SVRCONN channel and not other channels like RCVR... Secondly, if I need to connect to RCVR or any other channel, what changes do I need to make in the code?

Comment: Applications **ONLY** ever connect to a `SVRCONN` channel.  All other channel types are used to connect different queue managers together, not for applications to connect to.  It is not possible to change your code to connect to a `RCVR` channel for example, that is not the purpose of a `RCVR` channel.  Why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the channel name in,  `cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);`

If you use `cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "MYOTHERCHANNEL");`
it would try to use that channel name instead of what you had specified